# Access Random Number for Each Record Based on Count of a Field

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to generate a random number for each record in a query.  the number has to be between 1 and the count of a field.  I have tried this

```
Int((0-(Count(IIf([ID]=4441,"")))+1)*Rnd()+(Count(IIf([ID]=4441,""))))
```

and I think it's working except that it gives me the same number for every record.  If I do `Rnd([field])` it gives a different number for each record, but those numbers are between 0 and 1.  How do I get the best of both worlds and get a different number for each field based on my specific criteria?

Thanks

Comment: So you want unique numbers that are between 1 and 4441?

Comment: no I want a number between 1 and however many records have that value in the ID field.  It'll change all the time.  I may have written the IIf statement wrong, `Count(IIf([ID]=4441,[ID],""))` might be more correct

Comment: So you do not mind having repetitive numbers? Could you please edit your original post to show some sample data and the result you hope to see?

Answer (score 0):

"Random" will yield duplicate results since you didn't ask for unique random results, here a correct way to yield random numbers:

The correct syntax for Random is:

```
Int ((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
```

in your case

```
Exp: Int(((total) - 0 +1) * Rnd + 0)
```

read more here: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/rnd.php

**EDIT:**

so i did some play around and came with this:

```
Select T1.ID,
(SELECT top 1 Int((count(*)-0+1)*Rnd()+0) From tbl_table as T2 where T2.ID = T1.ID)
From tbl_Table as T1
```

or create a public function in your module:
something like this:

```
Public Function GET_RAND(i As Long, UV As Long, LV As Long) As Long
    'i is no where used it just forces access to process this function rather than getting the result from cache
    GET_RAND = Int((UV - LV + 1) * Rnd + LV)
End Function
```

and access it within the query like this:

```
SELECT T1.id, get_rand([id],(select count(*) from tbl_table),0) AS Expr1
FROM tbl_table AS T1;
```

*for me personally this is useless, unless i don't care about duplicate results. Maybe you could add some more code and make this better suited to your needs*

Comment: @PaulFrancis thank to you, i've learned access caches the UDF function's call method to present result.

Comment: I would change the subquery as `(SELECT TOP 1 Int((Count(*) - T1.ID + 1) * Rnd() + T1.ID) From tbl_table as T2 where T2.ID = T1.ID) AS tmpExp FROM tbl_table AS T1;`. With no different value for each record, the only values you seem to get are 0 and 1.

Comment: thank you so much for your work but I actually want it do give me a unique number for every record.  Does this change what you wrote here?